# How can I control the direction of AnimatedVisibility in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have used compose `AnimatedVisibility` in my project, I want to change direction of AnimatedVisibility for `slideInVertically()` from bottom to top and `slideOutVertically()` from top to bottom. How can this be done?

```
 AnimatedVisibility(
   visible = state.value,
   enter = slideInVertically(),
   exit = slideOutVertically())
    {

        // ...

    }
```

Comment: You are supposed to accept an answer when your query has been resolved. The grey tick underneath the votes counter is to indicate the answer solved your problem, which clearly Sir Alexandar Abhimanyu's answer here did.

Answer (score 15):

Use `initialOffsetY` and `targetOffsetY` like this to change the animation direction.

```
enter = slideInVertically(
    initialOffsetY = {
        it / 2
    },
),
exit = slideOutVertically(
    targetOffsetY = {
        it / 2
    },
),
```

---

**Source:** `EnterExitTransition.kt` source code

> This slides in the content vertically, from a starting offset defined in initialOffsetY to 0 in pixels. The direction of the slide can be controlled by configuring the initialOffsetY. A positive initial offset means sliding up, whereas a negative value would slide the content down.

> This slides out the content vertically, from 0 to a target offset defined in targetOffsetY in pixels. The direction of the slide-out can be controlled by configuring the targetOffsetY. A positive target offset means sliding down, whereas a negative value would slide the content up.