# Jetpack compose - animateDp - animation not showing in false case

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am trying to build a dialog bottom sheet, which i need to show a bottom sheet like thing over all composables with that sliding up and down, also with touch outside to dismiss behaviour.
In order to show above all elements i wrapped this in to a dialog and used update transition to translate height of the card inside dialog which is made to appear at the bottom of the screen.
The visibility is handled by a boolean value . The issue is that the animation is showing when when visibility is true. But it just fades out when visibility is false instead of showing sliding down animation.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun DialogBottomSheets(
    isVisible: Boolean,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val mutableInteractionSource = MutableInteractionSource()

    var visibility by remember(isVisible) {
        mutableStateOf(isVisible)
    }

    val transition = updateTransition(visibility, label = "Translation")
    val screenHeight = rememberWindowInfo().screenHeight

    val translateY by transition.animateDp(
        transitionSpec = {
            tween(200)
        }, label = "TranslationY to card"
    ) { isVisible ->
        if (isVisible) 0.dp else screenHeight
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = visibility,
        enter = fadeIn(
            animationSpec = keyframes {
                this.durationMillis = 200
            }
        ),
        exit = fadeOut(
            animationSpec = keyframes {
                this.durationMillis = 200
            }
        ),
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .zIndex(2f)
    ) {

        Dialog(
            onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() },
            properties = DialogProperties(
                usePlatformDefaultWidth = false,
                ),
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(color = Color.Transparent)
                    .clickable(mutableInteractionSource, null) {
                        Log.i("ONCLICK-DialogBottomSheets","Box")
                        onDismiss()
                    }
                ,
                contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
            ) {
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                        .offset(x = 0.dp, y = translateY)
                        .zIndex(2f)
                      /*  .clickable(mutableInteractionSource, null) {
                            // Nothing here to override click above the cards to implement dismiss on click outside behaviour
                        }*/
                    ,
                    backgroundColor = Color.White,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 24.dp, topEnd = 24.dp)
                ) {
                    content()
                }
            }
        }


    }


}
```

Compose version - 1.2.0. I cant use Bottom sheet from compose as this is built for project which interops xml .
Here is my code. How to show animation sliding down , when the visibility goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have no explanation why it is not working with your current approach, but did you try to slide the Dialog into the screen using `AnimatedVisibility` functionality instead of `animateDp`? You can combine the `fadeIn` animation with slide animations using the `+` operator as [explained in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#animatedvisibility). A solution could look as follows, you might need to adjust it in some way:

```
AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = visibility,
    enter = fadeIn(
            animationSpec = keyframes {
                this.durationMillis = 200
            }
        ) + 
        slideInVertically(
            initialOffsetY = {
                it / 2
            }
        ),
    exit = fadeOut(
            animationSpec = keyframes {
                this.durationMillis = 200
            }
        ) + 
        slideOutVertically(
            targetOffsetY = {
                it / 2
            },
        )
    ),
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .zIndex(2f)
) {
    // ...
}
```

The `initialOffset` values are set to define from which direction the slide in or slide out should happen, as explained in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73600576/8331157).

Comment: It didn't work too @BenjyTech

Comment: What exactly didn't work, or what was the behavior that it showed?

Comment: It worked as the same before , the exit animation is not showing